# TempData not persisting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I have a controller that sets TempData before returning a view,

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, int? order)
{
    Route route = new Route();
    // Do Work
    TempData["Route"] = route;
    return View(new FormViewModel(route, obj1, obj2));
}
```

This view contians a partial view with a link which goes to another action method called delete, the code for the delete link is:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { order = item.Order })%>
```

The code for the Delete action method is:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int order)
{
    Route route = (Route)TempData["Route"];
    // Do Work
}
```

The problem that I'm having is when I try to get TempData["Route"]; from the Delete action method is returning null.

I'm wondering if the issue is that this is a Get and not a Post?  If so how can I do a Post to the Delete ActionMethod from within my form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TempData persist between two requests. What does the ReturnView method in your Edit action returns? As far as I can tell it is not a standard method defined in the Controller class. Are you redirecting in this method (i.e. returning a RedirectToRouteResult)?

Also are there any other requests that could occur between your Edit and Delete actions? For example ajax requests.

Generally it is not a good idea to use TempData to persist something for a long time. The pattern usually is the following:

```
public ActionResult Update() 
{
    // When you put something into the TempData dictionary you usually
    // redirect immediately to an action that will use the object stored
    // inside.
    TempData["something"] = "something";
    return RedirectToAction("success");
}

public ActionResult Success() 
{
    var something = TempData["something"];
    return View();
}
```

If you need to persist something for a longer time you should use Session.

Comment: I've edited the post, it was a typo, should have been return View() not returnview.

Comment: How about ajax requests that could invalidate TempData?

Comment: Fixed it, it was a problem with SessionState.  Sorted it out with a few changes to the web.config.

Comment: I take it back, I added SessionState mode="InProc" into the SessionState but it's changed my nice looking URL's from http://localhost:4402/Route/Edit/1 to: http://localhost:4402/(S(e23msb30lb3u4vzbhlkhkajx))/Route/Edit/1 Any ways round this?  I don't have any AJAX requests that invalidate TempData.

Comment: The "token" you see in the url is when you disable cookies for session tracking. Just set cookieless="false" in sessionState and your urls will be nice again.

Comment: When I set cookieless="false" the TempData is not persisted. I've checked browser settings to allow cookies. If I have cookieless="true" then the TempData is persisted, any reason you can think of?

Comment: Install Firebug (if not already installed), open the "net" tab and perform the request. Inspect the headers. Is there a "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie sent with your request?

Answer (score 1):

Another factor of TempData not working is when your App is under a distributed system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it turned out that we had made our `SessionStateBehavior` `readonly`, in an implementation of `IControllerFactory`.  I changed this to `default`, and then got a subsequent error relating to Session State not being available and something about Registry keys... this error was solved on my local machine by starting the `Asp.Net State Service` in Windows Services.

TempData requires the use of Session State between requests.

Hope this helps someone.